# MySQL chain inner JOIN error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

When I log a user, I would like to retrieve his personal information such as his classes and teams. I managed to retrieve the classes, but when I try to retrieve the team it doesn't work.

I have 3 tables (users, teams and classes) and 2 join tables (teams_users and classes_users).

Relation below:

```
classes (id_classe) <--> classes_users (classe_id, user_id ) <--> users (id_user)
```

```
teams (id_team) <--> teams_users (team_id, user_id) <--> users (id_user)
```

This worked

```
SELECT * FROM classes `c` 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM classes_users `cu` 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM users WHERE (users.email = 'tata@gmail.com'))
`u` ON (u.id_user = cu.user_id)) 
`ui` ON (ui.classe_id = c.id_classe)
```

But when I tried to add another join below it didn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM teams_users `tu` 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM classes `c` 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM classes_users `cu` 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM users WHERE (users.email = 'tata@gmail.com')) 
`u` ON (u.id_user = cu.user_id))
`ui`ON (ui.classe_id = c.id_classe)) 
`wc` ON (wc.id_user = tu.user_id)
```

Comment: I think the error in your query is the brackets in WHERE (users.email = 'tata@gmail.com'). If you loose the brackets in this, it will work. But Gordon's answer below is the most concise way to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why all the parentheses and subqueries?  I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM teams_users tu INNER JOIN 
     users u
     ON u.id_user = tu.user_id INNER JOIN
     class_users cu
     ON u.id_user = cu.user_id INNER JOIN
     classes c
     ON cu.classe_id = c.id_classe
WHERE u.email = 'tata@gmail.com';
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand what I did wrong. I was using a query builder squel I return back to Native query. Most importantly I used u.team_id = t.id_team instead of tu.team_id = t.id_team